# Batch change multiple file names in bash and save output

Tags: bash, for-loop, command-line

I'm trying to change multiple file names with a for loop.

This works to send the output to the screen:

```
for i in *.gz; do echo $i | sed 's/\-//g'; done
```

However, when I try to overwrite the file name using `sed -i`, I get this error:

```
for i in *.gz; do echo $i | sed -i 's/\-//g'; done
sed: no input files
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your intention here?  To remove the `-` character from the names of your .gz files?  How are you using `sed -i`? Include that code in your question so that it is clear.  See this related post: [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1136/201820) on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just trying to remove the hyphens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Perl `rename` instead:

```
rename 's/-//g' *.gz
```

Or use simple [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for i in *.gz; do mv -- "$i" "${i//-}"; done
```

Comment: Thanks, rename worked. Just curious though, why doesn't sed -i work in this case?

Comment: @AlexBlumenfeld Because `sed` simply edited the text sent to it by `echo`. It didn't actually work with any files, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

there is a command for this

```
$ rename - '' *.gz
```

NB. this is the standard one, not the advanced `perl` version.